# Jquery sortable - limit droppables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I will simplify my explanation so you get what I am doing. I have two div's and I set up portlets as shown [here](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets), however I am dynamically injecting my portlets, no big problem there.

```
<div id="mainallapplicant" class="myrow"></div>
<div id="contingent_right" class="myrow"></div>
```

Here is the JavaScript

```
$( ".myrow" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".myrow",
    revert: true,
    beforeStop: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

I am trying to allow a maximum of only one droppable into mainallapplicant. If there is one already there, I will show a confirmation dialog and depending on the answer, I cancel the drop or move out the existing item and replace it with the new item. I tried the following but I am getting nowhere.

```
$( ".myrow" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".myrow",
    revert: true,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).prev().find(".portlet").length == 1) {
            ui.sender.draggable("cancel");
        }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).prev().find(".portlet").length == 1) {
            ui.item.remove();
            // Show an error...
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `start` to get the current count of portlet elements, then use `stop` to do the checking
Also notice I added class names to each div to allow only one div to have a maximum of 1 portlet

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.count = 0;
    $(".myrow").sortable({
        connectWith: ".myrow",
        revert: true,
        start: function () {
            $.count = $(".myrow").has(".portlet").length;
            console.log("Start " + $.count);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.item).parent(".myrow").hasClass("left")) {
                if ($.count == 2) {
                    $(".myrow").sortable("cancel");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Ue4dq/